# jquery tool tps not showing

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I have a learning game I'm designing.  I have 6 categories that I am randomly loading and want to display a dynamic description of the category.

```
function loadCategories() {
   var i = 0;
   var j = 0;

   $(".categoryname").each( function() {
    $(this).attr("title",descriptions[categoryIndex[i]]);
    $(this).text(category[categoryIndex[i]]).delay(500 * i);
    console.log("category "+ categoryIndex[i] + 
            ": "+category[categoryIndex[i]]+"\ttitle: " +
            descriptions[categoryIndex[i]]);
    $(this).fadeIn(2000,"blind");
    for(j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
       $(".value[index="+ (5*i + j) + "]").attr("answerid",categoryIndex[i]*5 + j);
    }

    i++;
   });

}
```

I can see the title for each category is being assigned in the console log.  However, at runtime I only see the tooltips for the last 3 categories.

I envoke the tooltip in the

```
$(document).ready( function () {

    // other code to parse the xml data file

    $(document).tooltip();

    // 

});
```

Each categoryname is a span that looks like:

```
<span class="categoryname" title=""></span>
```

until the title is set with the above code.  When I look at the code at runtime it shows correctly like:

```
<span class="categoryname" title="Tooltip">Category Name</span>
```

Any thoughts on why this is not working?

Comment: which version of jquery ui are you using? Do you have any errors? If you add a default title, does it work? :)

Comment: I'm using jquery 1.9.1 and jquery-ui 1.10.1.  No errors are shown in error console in FireFox.  I have tried using a default like `title="tooltip"` as suggested and i get the same behavior.  I have even tried applying tooltip to $(this) in the $(".categoryname").each function as well.

Comment: actually, in error console,  i'm seeing: **
Error: TypeError: st.easing[this.easing] is not a function
Source File: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js
Line: 3**

Comment: I think I  have figured out my problem. I have several divs that are beiing stacked  -- some  visibile, some not -- and although one isn't  visible, it's still on  top of my table that contains my categories.  I'm going to try adjusting the z-index of the table's div and see if that helps.